# What does this expression mean? SP_DEVINFO_DATA devdata = {sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)};

Tags: c++

I saw the c++ code written like this, it can pass the compilation with MSVC.

```
SP_DEVINFO_DATA devdata = {sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)};
```

What does this expression mean? I have never see the code like this before.

Someone can help?

Comment: It means the first field in that structure is a size-of-this-struct member, which is set to (what else) the sizeof the struct. After that, the remaining members are zero-filled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). In this case, it is explicitly initializing the first member of `devdata` only (the remaining are value initialized, thanks to [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) for commenting and making me add this), presumably a field that holds the number of bytes in size, to the size of the structure.

---

From the [`SP_DEVINFO_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff552344(v=vs.85).aspx) reference page the first member is a `DWORD` named `cbSize` which is:

> The size, in bytes, of the SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure.

Comment: It does initialize the remaining members as well, not just the first member. Per C++11 § 8.5.1,p7, *"If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list."* Empty initializer lists perform value-intiialization on the unspecified remaining members, Value initialization leading to zero-initialization of scaler members (which is all this struct has) is then covered through C++11 § 8.5,p7 and C++11 § 8.5,p5. So it does hit them all.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yep. I meant explicitly initializing but have updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Np. I use this all the time in Windows programming that requires these struct arrangements. Beats the hell out of the old decl + memset + set-first-member-to-size bs from eons ago. Nice update. +1.

Answer (score 2):

This means:

> Initialize a automatic variable named `devdata`, of type
>   `SP_DEVINFO_DATA`, and set its first member to `sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)`.

It is common practice for WINAPI structures to expose the size of the structure in their first member. That way, code that operates on such a structure can examine this member to determine the version of the structure it is working with.

Answer (score 1):

This is how initialize a struct. You initialize the first member of the `SP_DEVINFO_DATA`-structure, which should be `cbSize` with the size of the struct. This is necessary for this particular case.